# Selected option in angular select without ng-init

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a select using `ng-options`. following is my select html

```html
<select name="courseHighSchool"
        ng-model="course._highSchoolSelected"
        ng-init="course._highSchoolSelected = course.HighSchoolId == undefined ? undefined : {HighSchoolId: course.HighSchoolId};"
        ng-change="course.HighSchoolId = course._highSchoolSelected.HighSchoolId;"
        ng-options="item.HighSchoolName for item in TEData.RecruitHighSchools track by item.HighSchoolId"
        required>
        <option></option>
</select>
```

I am following tips provided in this [article](http://gurustop.net/blog/2014/01/28/common-problems-and-solutions-when-using-select-elements-with-angular-js-ng-options-initial-selection/) to set the initial selected value, which i am getting from `course.HighSchoolId` and my options are in collection `TEData.RecruitHighSchools.`

I wanted to know if there is a better way I can achieve this.

Comment: Set the value of course._highSchoolSelected in your controller before render.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `ng-init` just create a field under your `$scope`. Bind the field to the `<select>` element using the `ng-model` directive. That will get you the exact high school object that you are looking for.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hvsapa23/)

Answer (score 0):

set scope variable course._highSchoolSelected in the controller to the default value.This will render the control with that default value.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, consider elaborating your answer a little bit.